# RAII objects tr1:shared_ptr

Tags: c++, raii

I'm reading Scott Meyrses' C++ and come across the following code:

```
class Lock {
public:
explicit Lock(Mutex *pm) // init shared_ptr with the Mutex
    : mutexPtr(pm, unlock) // to point to and the unlock func
{
    lock(mutexPtr.get()); // see Item15 for info on “get”
}
private:
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<Mutex> mutexPtr; // use shared_ptr
}; // instead of raw pointer
```

In a footnote, he said that the code is not exception-safe. So in [his blog](http://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/ec++3e-errata.html#p68LockCtorProb) he proposed to modify the constructor of the calss as follows:

```
explicit Lock(Mutex *pm)
{
    lock(pm);
    mutexPtr.reset(pm, unlock);
}
```

That's not clear why this code should work. We call the reset method on the not yet initialized `mutextPtr` (we removed the entry from the ctor-initializer). Why won't we get something lie `Segmenetation fault`?

Comment: `std::tr1` is way outdated, as well as the book. I would recommend you switch to [Effective Modern C++](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Modern-Specific-Ways-Improve/dp/1491903996) if you are happy with Scott Meyers's style or something from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mutexPtr` is not uninitialized. When you leave something out of the initializer list, its default constructor is called, if it has one. `shared_ptr` has a default constructor, which sets the held pointer to null (i.e. no object is managed). The call to `reset` then sets it to manage `pm`. Nothing is deleted, because nothing was held. Even if `delete` was called on the held pointer, `delete` on a null pointer is a no-op, so it's not a problem.